# Rearranging a table

Tags: r

I am trying to make the output of my columns be the categories in which my data is separated in. Is there a way to transform the data with some functions so that I am able to get a copy of what I have below versus having to create the table from scratch?

[image: What I have versus what I want]

Comment: Downvote in hopes that your  next question doesn't use image to present data.

Comment: @IRTFM You have noticed, that the downvote button is for lack of research, unclear and not usefull questions and not for -admittedly very bad- style.

Comment: @Bernhard. Surely a duplicate. No evidence of searching. Unclear in that there is no code or data in a useful form. Nothing to act as a useful target for future users.Not just "bad style" but a generally low quality question by several standards.

Comment: @IRTFM thank you for the feedback. I will keep this in mind when creating new questions. I did search a ton about this problem though. If you have any ideas on how one typically demonstrates that, I would like to know. Thank you.

Comment: @IRTFM I am with you with that explanation.

Comment: @user22770348 Start out by stating the question in detail. I search on the terms I am going to put in my title and sort by score before reviewing. I then say why the top ten answers did not meet my needs. Your question is a common one. The original R  had a poorly documented function named `reshape` which was very difficult to use. Besides `ggplot2`, @hadley wrote a set of replacements for that function in a package named `reshape` which was superseded by `reshape2` and `plyr` and finally by `dplyr` and `tidyr` which has the various `pivot_*` functions that people now often use.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to pivot your data into a wide format.

The janitor library can add the totals.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- read_table("Sex Status n
                 M s 1
                 M t 2
                 F s 3
                 F t 4")
df

df %>% pivot_wider(names_from=Status, values_from=n)

#  Sex       s     t
#  M         1     2
#  F         3     4

library(janitor)
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=Status, values_from=n) %>% 
  adorn_totals(c("row", "col"))

 #    Sex s t Total
 #     M 1 2     3
 #     F 3 4     7
 # Total 4 6    10
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know what this "procedure" was called. Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!